# How to remove space between square brackets in vb.net?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using VB.NET to write a winforms application, how can I use regular expression to remove spaces between "[" and "]" in a string?

For example, for a string

```
"[Product Name] Like '%Dragon Ball%' AND [Product Type] Like '%Toy%'"
```

I want the result to be

```
"[ProductName] Like '%Dragon Ball%' AND [ProductType] Like '%Toy%'"
```

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
Public Function RemoveSpaceInFieldNames(ByVal expression As String) As String
  Dim regex As RegularExpressions.Regex = New       
  RegularExpressions.Regex(String.Format("\{0}\s*\{1}", "[", "]"))
  Return regex.Replace(expression, String.Empty)
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5D*%29%5Cs&i=%5BProduct%20Name%5D%20Like%20%27%25Dragon%20Ball%25%27%20AND%20%5BProduct%20Type%5D%20Like%20%27%25Toy%25%27&r=)

```
(?<=\[[^]]*)\s
```

- `(?<=\[[^]]*)` Positive lookbehind ensuring the following matches

  - `\[` Match `[` literally
  - `[^]]*` Match any character except `]` any number of times
- `\s` Match any whitespace character

You can append `(?=[^[]*])` if you want to ensure there's a `]` sometime afterwards as well, but, based on your sample, I don't think this is necessary.

Alternatively, you can also use `\s(?=[^[]*])` with the `Right to Left` modifier as [this link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%5B%5D*%5D%29&i=%5BProduct%20Name%5D%20Like%20%27%25Dragon%20Ball%25%27%20AND%20%5BProduct%20Type%5D%20Like%20%27%25Toy%25%27&r=&o=r&s=67) shows.

Replace with an empty string.

Result: `[ProductName] Like '%Dragon Ball%' AND [ProductType] Like '%Toy%'`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much ctwheels! Your answer works perfectly!!!

```
Public Function RemoveSpaceInFieldNames(ByVal expression As String) As String
    Dim regex As RegularExpressions.Regex = New RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<=\[[^]]*)\s")
    Return regex.Replace(expression, String.Empty)
End Function
```